# Inserting Date and time from two text boxes

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008

Inserting Date and Time from two separate Text Boxes. and concatenating for save to database.
I have seen lots of examples for `datetime` conversions but didn't get any clue.
advance in thanks

```cs
DateTime Datetime = Dateconversion.ConvertToDate(txtDate.Text.Trim());
DateTime time = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTime.Text);
```

```sql
insert into table(date) values('"+Datetime+" "+time+"')
```

Comment: Have you thought about putting the two strings together before converting it to a DateTime-object? You can also use DateTime.ParseExact, so you can be sure that it will parse it in the format you are providing.

See more at: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)
[DotNetPerls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-parse)

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. i am getting this error by using above code

Comment: Could you provide an example of the date you are trying to convert?

Comment: Date is coming from Ajax Toolkit calendar, like "06/19/2015 12:00:00"

Comment: ASP:TextBox supports datetime as a mode, in most browser this will let the user pick a time and date on a calender, and the format will be consistent, thereby avoiding exceptions.

Comment: It can be done through the designer, or by manually editing:

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" TextMode="DateTime">`

Comment: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/  just now i have tried these but there is no error message as well as no output

Answer (score 3):

**First**, never use Convert.ToDateTime directly on user input, since it's going to throw exceptions when the input is not convertible to datetime.
Instead, use [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.TryParse(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact.`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.TryParseExact(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Second**, never concatenate strings to create an sql statement, since it's an open door for [sql injections attacks](https://xkcd.com/327/). Use [parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx) instead.

Your code should look something like this:

```
DateTime DateTimeValue;
string DateTimeString = txtDate.Text.Trim() +' '+ txtTime.Text.Trim();
if(DateTime.TryParse(DateTimeString, out DateTimeValue))
{
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString")) {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into table(date) values(@Value)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Value", SqlDbType.DateTime).value = DateTimeValue;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since he is using ASP textboxes, he could use the DateTime "mode" for it, and then getting a consistent format of the inputstring.

Comment: @MalteR It's been a long time since my asp.net days, I was not aware of that option. does it also keep you from inserting dates like 29th of february if the year is not a leap year?

Comment: I have to pass the date and time value to other class file..    DateTime DateTimeValues;
        string DateTimeString = txtDate.Text.Trim() + ' ' + txtTime.Text.Trim();
        if (DateTime.TryParse(DateTimeString, out DateTimeValues))
        {
            ViewState["Datetime"] = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimeString);
        }
        DateTime datetime = (DateTime) ViewState["Datetime"];    it is working in trace mode. when i run directly it is working

Comment: So convert them to datetime before passing them to the other class, or inside the other class, that makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: It is working fine but done in every page refreshment not is postback

Comment: Is it inside a condition on Page.IsPostBack?

Comment: No..inside button click event

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81002/discussion-between-vikram-and-zohar-peled).

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to concatenate the strings before converting it to date time object.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope it will help.Please use TryParseExact, do not directly convert user input to date time, can cause serious issues.